# images change in display div as you mouse over links another div

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two `DIV` elements.
 Inside `DIV_1` i want certain images to be display when called upon, in `DIV_2` i will have many `LINKS`.

When each individual `LINK` in `DIV 2` is **hovered** I want the **link-related image** to appear in `DIV 1`, then change to another pic if another `LINK` is **hovered**, but also make it disappear when the mouse arrow doesn't hover over the specific `LINK`.

**Javascript**

```
function showIt(imgsrc) 
{
    document.getElementById('bottle').src=imgsrc;
    document.getElementById('bottle').style.display='block';
}

function hideIt()
{
    document.getElementById('bottle').style.display='none';
}
```

Comment: show us your markup as well as clearing the code a bit please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your links this code :

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="showIt('some_image.jpg')" onmouseout="hideIt()" >...</a>
```

However it wont look pretty. Consider using jQuery.

**EDIT:**

Using jQuery you could do this way:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-src="some.jpg" class="changeImage" >...</a>
<a href="#" data-src="another.jpg" class="changeImage" >...</a>
...
<img class="bottle" />
```

JavaScript

```
$(function(){
  $('.changeImage').hover(function(){
         $('.bottle').attr('src',$(this).attr('data-src'));
         $('.bottle').show();
     },
     function(){
         $('.bottle').hide();
     });

})
```

You can adjust animation speed by providing animation time as argument to show() and hide(). 
URL for images put in data-src attributes of a tags.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that you might consider would be setting the `background-image` property in CSS and then adding the `:hover` pseudo-class to change to the new image, saving you from having to deal with Javascript at all.

Using the `transition` property, you could even add a fade between the two images with no additional work on your part, or the need to include another library like jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some simple jQuery you could use:

```
$('#DIV1').delegate('a', 'mouseenter mouseleave', function (e) {
    if (e.type === "mouseenter") {
        switch ($(this).attr('href')) {
            case "#link1":   
                $('#DIV2').html('<img src="image1.jpg" />');
                break;
            case "#link2":   
                $('#DIV2').html('<img src="image2.jpg" />');
                break;
        }
    } else if (e.type === "mouseleave") {
        $('#DIV2 img').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/opefik/4/edit)*

if you have something like this:

```
  <div id="images">
    <img src="img1.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="img2.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="img3.jpg" alt="" />  
  </div>
  
  <ul id="links">
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
  </ul>
```

CSS:

```
#images img{position:absolute;display:none;}
```

than you need just this:

```
$('#links li').on('mouseenter mouseleave',function(e){
    $('#images img').stop().fadeTo(300,0);    // do on mouseenter and mouseleave
    if(e.type=='mouseenter'){                 // do just on mouseenter
        $('#images img').eq( $(this).index() ).stop().fadeTo(300,1);
    }
});
```